# webhook jenkıns 400 invalid http response

Tags: github, jenkins

I will use github and jenkins for my clone project, but I get 400 error in github webhook. Could someone please help/explain what is causing this? Thanks in advance
[image: webhook github jenkins integration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. If you can't solve this error, don't forget to add a secret when creating the webhook. You can get secret from configuration > api token